# Copy first row in excel workbook to a new excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How do I get the first row in an excel workbook & save it to a new excel workbook using .net c#? I dont know the amount of columns so need to get entire row. This what I have but the new workbook is blank (no row copied)

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file);    
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];    
Excel.Range xlRangeHeader = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow;                         
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbookNew = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();    
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheetNew = xlWorkbookNew.Sheets[1];    
xlWorksheetNew.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value = xlRangeHeader;                        
xlWorkbook.Close(false);                        
xlWorkbookNew.SaveAs(Path.Combine(sDestination, Path.GetFileName(file)), fileFormat);                        
xlWorkbookNew.Close(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
xlWorksheetNew.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value = xlRangeHeader.Value;
```

or

```
xlWorksheetNew.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value;
```

Comment: Ahh, I tried .value but I had the range wrong, I never tried it again with the correct range format. Thanks. Top line works.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void test(Application xlApp)
{
    string file = @"C:\Temp\a.xlsx";
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    xlWorksheet.Range["A1"].EntireRow.Copy(); 
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbookNew = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheetNew = xlWorkbookNew.Sheets[1];
    Worksheet activeSheet = xlWorkbookNew.ActiveSheet;
    activeSheet.Paste();

    xlWorkbook.Close(false);
    xlWorkbookNew.SaveAs(Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", Path.GetFileName(file)));
    xlWorkbookNew.Close(true);
    CloseExcel();
}

public void CloseExcel(Application xlApp)
{
    try
    {
        if (xlApp != null)
        {
            xlApp.Quit();
            if (Marshal.IsComObject(xlApp))
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I was going to get into the low level stuff but didn't know your level of expertise. If you want good performance dont use the Copy/Paste. Here I'll show you a couple of perf tricks. Firstly write to all cells at once:

```
object[,] values = (object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new int[2] { rowCount, ColumnCount }, new int[2] { 1, 1 });
```

//Populate the values here and then write the data to Excel in one fowl swoop:

```
using (var targetRange = xlApp.Range[topLeft + startRow + ":" + rightBottom + endRow].WithComCleanup())
{
   targetRange.Resource.Value2 = values;
}
```

Secondly notice the `.WithComCleanup()` - when doing VSTO coding you need to be aware of managing the unmanaged memory - http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop.

Comment: How does copy perform when looping through a large amount of spreadsheets? I was trying to keep away from the clipboard code as I'm going to loop through a heap of excel files.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, how would I integrate that perf trick into the code I have now? Thanks. Tony.

Comment: Simply download the VSTOContrib.Core.DLL and VSTOContrib.Excel.DLL and reference them in your project. To populate the object[,] use two for loops that start at 1, as Excel is Base 1.