# C#- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel copy a specific row from an excel to another excel instance and delete that row afterwards

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, office-interop, excel-interop

What I'm trying to achieve is that, based on a email verification, to copy the entire row from one excel instance to another one and delete that row afterwards. The thing is that none of my methods ( copy the row and delete it ) work at this point and for some reason, once I run my code, both files become `read only`.

Sorry for any mistake made, but this is my first question here.

Do you see anything wrong regarding my code? Or can you please explain how this should look like?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CleanUpUserList
{
    public class Program
    {

        static Regex ValidEmailRegex = CreateValidEmailRegex();
        private static string invalidUserFileName = @"C:\Users\Sebastian Cocirla\Desktop\To.xlsx";
        private static string validUserFileName = @"C:\Users\Sebastian Cocirla\Desktop\From.xlsx";
        private static string saveAsFileName = "SSO Member List NON SECUTIX - INValid.xlsx";
        private static string mailToMatchForInvalidation = "mailinator";
        private static char mailSeparator = '@';
        private static char domainSeparator = '.';

        static void Main()
        {
            CleanUpExcelFile();
        }

        public static void CleanUpExcelFile()
        {
            int newWorkbookIndex = 0;

            Application app = new Application();

            Workbook validUserFile = app.Workbooks.Open(validUserFileName);
            Worksheet validUserWorksheet = validUserFile.Sheets[1];

            Workbook invalidUserFile = app.Workbooks.Open(invalidUserFileName);
            Worksheet invalidUserWorksheet = invalidUserFile.Sheets[1];

            Range range = validUserWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rows = range.Rows.Count;

            validUserWorksheet.Activate();
            invalidUserWorksheet.Activate();

            for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
            {

                var emailAddress = range.Cells[rowIndex, 8].Value2.ToString();

                if (!EmailIsValid(emailAddress))
                {
                    newWorkbookIndex++;

                    CopyRow(validUserFile, invalidUserFile, validUserWorksheet, invalidUserWorksheet, rowIndex, newWorkbookIndex);

                    ((Range)validUserWorksheet.Rows[rowIndex]).Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
                }
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(validUserWorksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(invalidUserWorksheet);

            validUserFile.Close();
            invalidUserFile.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(validUserFile);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(invalidUserFile);

            app.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        }

        private static void CopyRow(Workbook validUserFile, Workbook invalidUserFile, Worksheet validUserWorksheet,
            Worksheet invalidUserWorksheet, int rowIndex, int newWorkbookIndex)
        {

            var selectedRow = validUserWorksheet.Range["A1:M1"];
            var destinationRow = invalidUserWorksheet.Range["A2:M2"];

            selectedRow.Copy(destinationRow);
            validUserFile.Save();
            invalidUserFile.Save();
        }

        private static Regex CreateValidEmailRegex()
        {
            string validEmailPattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"
                                       + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"
                                       + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";

            return new Regex(validEmailPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        private static bool EmailIsValid(string emailAddress)
        {
            var splitEmailHost = emailAddress.Split(mailSeparator);
            var hostLength = splitEmailHost[1].Split(domainSeparator)[0].Length;

            bool isValid = ValidEmailRegex.IsMatch(emailAddress)
                           && !splitEmailHost[1].Contains(mailToMatchForInvalidation)
                           && hostLength > 1;

            return isValid;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a specific row like,

```
Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow;
```

And use following statement to delete it.

```
range.Delete();
```

Then use `foreach` statement to traverse it and save it to another Excel file.

```
foreach (var i in range.Value)
{
    if (i != null)
        workSheet2.Cells[rowindex, columnindex++].Value = i;
}
```

Here is a simple demo.

```
// open excel1 and get specific row
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\test.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
if (workSheet == null)
    return;
Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow;

// open excel2
Excel.Application excel2 = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook2 = excel2.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\new.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
Excel.Worksheet workSheet2 = workBook2.Worksheets.Item[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
if (workSheet2 == null)
    return;

int rowindex = 12; // here is the rowindex that copy to
int columnindex = 1;

foreach (var i in range.Value)
{
    if (i != null)
        workSheet2.Cells[rowindex, columnindex++].Value = i;
}

range.Delete(); // delete the row

// save and close excel
excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
excel.Application.Quit();
excel.Quit();

excel2.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
excel2.Application.Quit();
excel2.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quick read of your code

```
var selectedRow = validUserWorksheet.Range["A1:M1"];
var destinationRow = invalidUserWorksheet.Range["A2:M2"];
```

Why not

```
var selectedRow = validUserWorksheet.Range["A" + rowIndex + ":M" + rowIndex];
var destinationRow = invalidUserWorksheet.Range["A" + newWorkbookIndex + ":M" + newWorkbookIndex];
```

---

For copy row :

- [Copy first row in excel workbook to a new excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399010/copy-first-row-in-excel-workbook-to-a-new-excel-workbook) << need to change Range

For delete row :

- [C# and excel deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255166/c-sharp-and-excel-deleting-rows)

Comment: that was for testing purposes only. will try the following links and come back with a reply.